# An error occurred while installing gcloud (0.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue - gcloud gem causes deploy to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I run `gcloud preview app deploy` the deploy runs fine until it gets upto the point where its installing the gems. It errors out with:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: bad response Not Found 404 (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/gcloud-0.8.1.gem)
Installing actionpack 4.2.0
Installing acts_as_commentable_with_threading 2.0.1
An error occurred while installing gcloud (0.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install gcloud -v '0.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --deployment && rbenv rehash' returned a non-zero code: 5
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/dockerizer" failed: exit status 1
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Not sure if this is a known error or if there is a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to [update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) your Google Cloud SDK and deploy your code again:

```
$ gcloud components update
```